# How to bind variable to textbox from other window?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have two windows: for example - window1 and window2. In window1 I have function which returns record from database and assigns this record to variable 'myVariable'. I'd like to bind this variable into textbox text in window2. How can I do that?

Comment: use MVVM and have both windows point to the same viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

In Window 1 
Declare myVariable as public static assign its value by your function 
In window2 
win2Textbox.Text=Win1.myVariable;